# XPath in Oraclize RSS query

Tags: oracles

I am trying to get my hands on Oraclize, testing some sample queries with their [Test query](http://app.oraclize.it/home/test_query) service. I can't get XML parser working with XPath. The [documentation](https://docs.oraclize.it/#general-concepts-parsing-helpers) lacks an XML example.

Consider [this simple feed](http://www.dictionary.com/wordoftheday/wotd.rss).

The following query returns `Dictionary.com Word of the Day`, as expected:

`xml(http://www.dictionary.com/wordoftheday/wotd.rss).rss.channel.title`

The following semantically equivalent query that uses XPath returns nothing:

`xml(http://www.dictionary.com/wordoftheday/wotd.rss).xpath(./rss/channel/title/text())`

How can I query an RSS feed with Oraclize and filter the results according to come criteria (e.g., items with `<user>` field equal to `Alice`, etc)?

Comment: But this works: `xml(http://www.dictionary.com/wordoftheday/wotd.rss).xpath(//rss/channel/title/text())`. Not sure if it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working - specify absolute rather than relative path in the XPath:

```
xml(http://www.dictionary.com/wordoftheday/wotd.rss).xpath(/rss/channel/title/text())
```